# 允可ス on Aikido Certificate - Meaning and Katakana Usage

Tags: translation, conjugations, katakana

I'm still a Nihongo Noob but recently I tried to translate my Aikido certificate for fun. The important part says:

> [my name] 
> 右者{みぎもの} 今般{こんぱん} 合気道{あいきどう} 
> 参段{さんだん} ヲ 允可{いんか}ス

which basically translates to "Person to the right - now - Aikido - 3rd rank - permission (?)"

What struck me first was that the object marker ヲ and the ス are in Katakana. I found out that this is common practice in official documents and sometimes a matter of fashion.

1. Can someone confirm this, please?

Second I could not find out the function of the ス. According to Jisho 允可{いんか} (permission) can be both a noun and a suru-verb.

2. If it's a noun, what does the ス mean here? And if it's used as a suru-verb, what kind of strange conjugation of する applies here?

Comment: Possible duplicate (regarding the す): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2436/9831

Comment: For katakana: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14848/7810

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for your hint. So if I understand this correctly, the classical す equals the modern する? Would a proper translation of 允可する then be "is permitted" or "has permission"?

Comment: ～～を允可する。"We permit ~~." ですかね。。

Comment: Congratulations on the 3rd Dan, that's an impressive achievement (I am 3rd kyu)!! Are you in Aikikai?

Comment: @jarmanso7 ありがとうございます。Yes, I'm in Aikikai, studying the style of Endo Sensei.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

允可ス is 允可する in modern Japanese. す is the [classical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Japanese) version of する. (允可 itself is rare in modern Japanese. We usually say 認可する or 認める today.)

Katakana was the default kana for particles, okurigana and such until relatively recently.

- [Orthography at the turn of the previous century](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14848/5010)
- [Why is this written in katakana instead of hiragana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50317/5010)