The (apparently) same sequence of symbols in an Aikido diploma results in weirdly different translations in Google Translator. Can someone explain?
According to the posting guidelines, this is a bit off-topic: I'm not learning Japanese. But I have two Aikido degree certificates where the part that seems to describe the degree results in different translations for the (apparently) same sequence of symbols, and one of them is really weird and doesn't seem to be related to the context in an obvious way.
Here is the "1st kyu" (that's how English-speaking folks refer to this degree):

Google Translator translates this as "1st class permission possible". This makes sense to me, something like "the holder of this certificate has permission to call themselves a student 1st class" or similar.
Experiments with Google also seem to indicate that the top two are the degree, and the bottom four are the "permission possible" part, also alone translated as "you can do it" by Google.
Now here is the "1st dan" or "shodan" (again that's how English-speaking folks refer to this degree):

The bottom four symbols seem to be the same as before, and Google translates them alone as the same "you can do it". But all symbols together are translated as "1st dan masturbation". I can't draw a context line from this to what (I think) it should mean.
I know that this is Google Translator, and it may be anybody's guess what it does. But maybe someone can explain how the combination of symbols and contexts work here to create this translation?
Thanks for any insights.

It's really not worth worrying about how/why machine translation sometimes messes up (unless you're a computer scientist of course). Here's a related link for the text on your certificate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/80730/%e5%85%81%e5%8f%af%e3%82%b9-on-aikido-certificate-meaning-and-katakana-usage

I can't reproduce this by typing in the text in Google Translate. If you mean that you used Google Glass, maybe something went wrong in its OCR.

@KarlKnechtel Thanks for the translator link! I produced the translations by uploading images in Google Translator (the "Images" button at the top). I don't think it's an OCR problem, because if I upload the bottom four symbols, it's the same translation for both. The top two symbols separately also create a translation that makes sense. Only when all are together is when the odd translation happens.

First thing's first:  Don't trust Google Translate with Japanese.  It's notoriously horrible.
Next, 允可.  This means "permission/compliance".  Since you're not studying Japanese, I won't try to explain in too much detail, but 允可ス is simply the verb form "to permit/comply".  The ヲ points to what is permitted/complied (direct object), which is the thing preceding it (Japanese grammar uses a different word order than English).
So that brings us to 一級 vs 初段.

一級: 一 is "1", and 級 is grade/level/rank.  So 一級 is "Level 1".
初段: 初 means "first", and 段 is degree/level/class/rank.  So 初段 is "First degree".

I don't know all the nuances of 級 vs 段, but their meanings and usage can overlap in many contexts, but not in others.  Clearly in the martial arts world (or at least Aikido), they do.
So the whole thing translates to "_____ permit Level 1/First Degree".  One thing to note (as shown by my blank space) is that there is nothing here that explicitly lists the "doer(s)" of the "permitting" action.  Japanese will often omit the doer if the context is clear.  So this means that the doer(s) would be understood to be like the head master(s) ("Sensei"s?) of the Dojo, or possibly the Dojo itself personified, or maybe even a higher governing board of Aikido—whoever has the authority to confer the rand & certificate to the individual.
Not sure how "masturbation" got thrown in the mix.   But that's why we never trust Google Translate.
Hope that helps!

"I don't know all the nuances of 級 vs 段, but their meanings and usage can overlap in many contexts, but not in others. Clearly in the martial arts world (or at least Aikido), they do."
I'm not sure I understood this part correctly, but in these certificates, 級 is the lower set of ranks ("kyu" ranks, white belts), and 段 is the higher set of ranks ("dan" ranks, black belts). So they overlap (in the sense that they are about rank), but they are also distinct (they are about different classes of ranks).

Ahh, OK.  Then they are much more nuanced with regard to Aikido.  Perhaps other martial arts as well.

Kyu ranks count down to first as you improve, then dan ranks count upward (and the first dan rank is always 初段, but the subsequent ranks are numbered from 2 onward). It's the same kyu-dan ranking system seen in other martial arts. Or in Go. Or in some video games.

@KarlKnechtel It's the same kyu-dan ranking system seen in other martial arts In France at least you would not really speak of kyu but instead go for belt colors. The colors vary wildly between countries (I recently discussed with a friend whose daughter is practicing karate and was awarded a "white-blue" belt - something that I've never seen in France). Ultimately a somehow common ground is the kyu but the students would not usually even know about these (they know their belt color and the ones remaining very well, though :)). Dan is in contrast common everywhere.

Just out of curiosity, any idea why the particles are written in katakana instead of hiragana here? Is that a martial arts thing? A diploma thing? Something else?

The katakana is, as far as I know, just tradition. It has more to do with the common writing practice at the time that the diploma-issuing practice started.

@WoJ The colors vary wildly by tradition more than by country, it’s just that country often coincides with sub-disciplines of a given tradition (because a given martial art in a particular country was often introduced by a single original dojo). But there are things that are generally very consistent. For example, pure white belts are almost always either ungraded or the lowest kyu for the discipline, and the highest kyu is usually some form of brown belt. And it often is different for kids too (may traditions do half-grades for kids, which is where many of the bi-color belts come in).

@AustinHemmelgarn yes, my comparison was between karate Kyokushin in France and Shotokan in Poland. In both cases there are bi-color belts for children (to slow down the progression, and yet give them a sense of pride of having mastered something) and between white and brown this is a complete mix-up.
